# Преобразование в дату в postgreSql

Tags: postgresql

Почему при запросе

```
select to_date(date,'YYYY-MM-DD') from mssql_bi
```

Выдаёт вот в таком формате

```
"0012-09-05"
```

А дата в оригинале

```
"19-05-2016"
```

Comment: ну если ожидать формат YYYY-MM-DD, а передать DD-MM-YYYY - то понятное дело получится что-то странное. Я впрочем ожидал ошибку. Но в реализации функции получается странный результат.

Comment: А какого у вас типа поле `date` в БД ? Может оно дата и тогда происходит неявное преобразование типа в строку, что бы передать его функции to_date, которая принимает строковый параметр. А так как формат даты по умолчанию при переводе в строку может отличаться от того что вы указали, то и получается совершенно другое и непонятное значение

Comment: А каким образом можно переформатировать дату в YYYYMMDD

Comment: @Егор, функцией TO_CHAR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно было переформатировать дату функцией TO_CHAR